# HttpClient behavior different between .net core 3.1 and .net 5

Tags: httpclient, .net-5, webhdfs

The below code retrieves a JSON document from a WebHDFS instance using Kerberos authentication:

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new()
{
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials,
    DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
};

using HttpClient client = new(clientHandler);

const string Url = "https://x.com:50470/webhdfs/v1?op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY";
string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);
```

This code works fine in .net core 3.1, and uses the current user's credentials to authenticate. But on .net 5, the exact same code produces a 403 error with a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` message returned by WebHDFS.

I've checked several documentations (for instance [this one](https://blog.miguelbernard.com/net-5-the-breaking-changes-you-need-to-know-about)) to try to understand what could cause the issue but didn't find anything.

I've also tried to use:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

but it didn't help.